# Python3: print statement of a variable leads to a different output

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, memory-management, lifetime

I write a Python script to manage my account on a webpage automatically.

**Code Description:**

The script has a while loop and at the end of the loop, it waits 12 hours before starting again.
**Before** the while loop starts, it's logging in to my account, and when **entering** the while loop, it checks if I'm still logged in. If not, it's logging in to my account again.

**Problem:**

After re-entering the while loop *(first time everything goes fine)*, the script does only work, when *print("Name is:")* and *print(name)* is at the very beginning. I tested it several times and maybe it is just a bug/glitch, which was just unlucky to be caused only when the print statements aren't there, but this is very confusing me right now, how those print statements fixed my issue. I would like to know, what is or could causing the issue and how do I have to solve it properly?

**Some side info:**

The webpage is saving the login credentials through session cookies with a lifetime of ~6 hours. So after re-entering the script loop again, I'm not logged in for sure. If I'm reducing the wait time to 30 minutes instead of 12 hours, the script works also without the print statements.

**General notes:**

- The script is running through nohup on my *Raspberry Pi 3*
- Python version is 3.7.3

**Code related notes:**

- I'm using the post method from *requests* to log in to my account
- For checking, if I'm still logged in, I'm using *beautifulSoup4*
- The following code is abbreviated and in a very basic shape.
- "account" is an instance of a self-made class. When instantiating, it is log in itself with arguments, if given

This is the core code:

```
import time
import requests
from account import Account # costum made class
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# login credentials
name = "lol" # I replaced them with placeholders
pw   = "lol" 

account = Account(name, pw) # instantiating an account class and log in itself with given arguments

while True: # script loop
    print("name is:") # Without those both print statements,
    print(name)       # the code won't work

    if not account.stillAlive():  # if not signed in anymore ...
        account.login(name, pw)   # ... sign in again

    account.doStuff() # Do the automating stuff

    time.sleep(43200) # Wait 12 hours, before entering the while loop again
```

This is the doStuff() method from the Account class:

```
def doStuff(self):
    html    = requests.get("example.com").text # Note: example.com is only for demonstration purpose only
    crawler = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    lol = crawler.find("input", attrs={"name": "Submit2"}).get("value")

    # ...
```

**Error message:**

So, if I'm executing the program without the print statements, I'm getting this error:

lol = crawler.find("input", attrs={"name": "Submit2"}).get("value")

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

This does not occur when executing with the print statements. With the print statements, the code runs fine.

**My guess**

My guess is, what the memory management of Python is deleting the name variable. When entering the script loop in the first time, I'm already logged in and therefore it is skipping the account.login(name, pw) part. Since this is the only part, where name is continued to be, maybe Python is interpreting this as dead code after too many time has passed without the line to be executed, and don't see the reason to keep the name/pw variable and deletes them. Still, I'm just an amateur and I don't have any expertise in this segment.

**Side notes:**

- This is my first question I'm submitting, if I forgot or did something wrong, pls tell me.
- I already searched for this problem, but I didn't find anything similar. Maybe I just searched badly, but I searched for a few hours now. If so, I apologize. (I had to wait for every test 12 hours and since I tried it several times, you can tell, I had ***some*** time available to search)

Comment: Are you sure that the html contains the `input` tag with the `attrs` you specify? If it does not, then the `crawler.find()` function call will return None. You can see if this is the problem by changing it to `crawler.find_all()`, and if it returns an empty list then that means it just hasn't found any examples matching your query.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reading at the first place.
It could be, what the html don't include the input tag. But I'm using the method with same specification in the first loop and it works without any problems. And with the print statements, it works also correctly. It would be very weird if this would be the problem. I will look for this, but I will have to wait 12 hours... So, I will have check this solution by tomorrow.

Comment: It's possible that the `Submit2` input is present only after you've just logged in but not if you were already logged in. Without knowing the site or its behaviour, it's hard to tell. Save/print the html of the page before the `doStuff` step and see if Submit2 is present both times/loops.

Comment: Ok, I now let the code run with following specifications: no print statements; The html variable in the doStuff() method gets saved in a file; If the account needs to sign in again (if not account.stillAlive():), it's printing the locals(), so I will be able to look for all saved variables. Everything is good so far. The doStuff() method worked as it should and the html was correct (including the **input** with **name="Submit2"**). Since the print statements are missing, I expect the code to failure, but I will check in 12 hours again and I will notify what happened.